# Can mods do a mass move?

Tags: discussion, migration

It's not every question (some are just plain bad questions), but I believe that most questions [tagged development-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/development-process) and a good number tagged [methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methodology) should be moved to Programmers. I could vote them all off-topic or flag all of them that I feel should be moved, but that seems like a headache. Votes might not get enough to move, and flags would just bombard the mods of SO. What is that the appropriate thing to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to do a mass move. If there were, I wouldn't recommend using it.

For one, we don't want to spam Programmers with 2-year-old answered questions that would push new questions off the front page. There's very little to be gained by that. We prefer to let the sleeping dogs lie and migrate things in on a case-by-case basis whenever the need arises (i.e. someone posts a question to Programmers that was answered well on SO -- we then ask SO mods to migrate it over).

For another, we have to be careful with quickly migrating old questions: because they might be off-topic on Stack Overflow doesn't mean they will be on topic or constructive for Programmers. Judging each question would be a pretty major undertaking, which is why it's generally not done.

If you come across questions that you feel absolutely **must** be on Programmers, flagging for a moderator to move them is likely your best bet.

Comment: Questions that are migrated don't go to their proper place in the line up? I thought if a 6 month old question was migrated, it would appear with other 6 month old questions on the site that it was moved to and not on the front page. Interesting to know that - that makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, migrated questions get treated as "new" on the site they're migrated to, for better or worse. For example, you probably wouldn't have found and answered [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/93628/best-practices-or-project-standards) if it had landed somewhere with the questions asked in 2009. :)

Comment: I didn't even notice the date it was asked. I just see a question that I can answer and answer it. If SE sites had a "random question", I'd be all over that.

Comment: @Thomas I hear ya. I just pulled that one out as a handy supporting example. :)

Comment: GET OFF MY LAWN!!! (+1, btw)